# Бэкграунд у активной ссылки

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при наведении на картинку и текст под ней, бэкграунд становился оранжевым?

Comment: приведите пример вашего кода.

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul, li {
  list-style:none;
}

.cat li {
  display: inline-table;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
}

/* Обратите внимание */

.cat li:hover {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<ul class="cat">
  <li><img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" width="100" /><br />Google</li>
  <li><img src="http://cdn.marketplaceimages.windowsphone.com/v8/images/98fe83a8-bd61-4dd5-9cbb-3b817d869bff?imageType=ws_icon_medium" width="100" /><br />Yandex</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать псевдокласс `:hover`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky описание для `hover`: Определяет стиль элемента при наведении на него курсора мыши, но при этом элемент еще не активирован, иными словами кнопка мыши не нажата.

Answer (score 0):

Пускай, вы заключаете ссылку, картинку, и текст под ней в блок с `id = div1`. Тогда так:

```
#div1:hover {
       backround:orange;
    }
```